# How to find the age of a remote branch without fetching the origin

Tags: git

How to delete a branch older than 30 days on remote without fetching the entire repo

i= remote branch name

```
if [ -n "$(git log -1 --since='30 days' -s $i)" ]; then
git push origin :$i
echo " Deleted Branch $i"
fi
```

can any one help me on it

Comment: I assume you are using bash. Is this Linux? Unix? OSX? Cygwin? Windows?

Comment: i am using windows and i am storing libraries on branch & now i need to delete all the branch that are older than few weeks  using jenkins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to know how old a given commit is, is to fetch it – the network protocol does not give access to such information in any other way.

If you don't want to fetch the *entire* repository, use Git's "shallow clone" mode to fetch just the latest commit:

```
git fetch --depth=1 ...
```

Comment: Thank You this fetch process works better but will slow down on large repositories